# Ошибка при отправке JAVAMAIL

Tags: java, android, javamail

И так, вот код:

```
import com.example.sendsapp.MailSenderClass;
import com.example.sendsapp.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class ExtendedMail extends Activity {


Context mainContext;

String title;
String text;
String from;
String where;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotline);

    mainContext = this;

    Button buttonsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsend);
    buttonsend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sender_mail_async async_sending = new sender_mail_async();
            async_sending.execute();
        }
    });
}

private class sender_mail_async extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog WaitingDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        WaitingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ExtendedMail.this, "Отправляем сообщение...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        WaitingDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(mainContext, "Отправлено", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((Activity)mainContext).finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {

        try {
            title = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
            text = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString();
            text1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3)).getText().toString();

            from = "myappmail@mail.as";
            where = "mymail@mail.as";

            MailSenderClass sender = new MailSenderClass("myappmail@mail.as", "password");

            sender.sendMail(title, text, from, where);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mainContext, "Ошибка отправки сообщения!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Вот лог ошибок:

```
05-30 12:09:56.043: I/Choreographer(6360): Skipped 272 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-30 12:09:56.233: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090000}
05-30 12:09:56.243: D/dalvikvm(6360): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 15% free 4752K/5580K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
05-30 12:09:56.243: I/dalvikvm-heap(6360): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.726MB for 1104672-byte allocation
05-30 12:09:56.253: D/dalvikvm(6360): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 13% free 5830K/6660K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
05-30 12:09:56.263: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090003}
05-30 12:09:56.273: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090004}
05-30 12:09:56.273: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090005}
05-30 12:09:56.283: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090006}
05-30 12:09:56.293: D/dalvikvm(6360): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 8% free 6993K/7528K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
05-30 12:09:56.303: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090007}
05-30 12:09:56.303: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090008}
05-30 12:09:56.313: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090009}
05-30 12:09:56.323: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f09000a}
05-30 12:09:56.333: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f09000b}
05-30 12:09:56.333: D/dalvikvm(6360): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 7% free 8429K/8972K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
05-30 12:09:56.343: W/Resources(6360): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090002}
05-30 12:10:03.283: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6360): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-30 12:10:14.503: W/dalvikvm(6360): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/sendsapp/ExtendedMail; (1630)
05-30 12:10:14.503: W/dalvikvm(6360): Link of class 'Lcom.example.sendsapp.ExtendedMail;' failed
05-30 12:10:14.503: E/dalvikvm(6360): Could not find class 'com.example.sendsapp.ExtendedMail', referenced from method com.example.sendsapp.MailSenderClass$Sender_mail_async.doInBackground
05-30 12:10:14.503: W/dalvikvm(6360): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1502 (Lcom/example/sendsapp/ExtendedMail;) in Lcom/example/sendsapp/MailSenderClass$Sender_mail_async;
05-30 12:10:14.503: D/dalvikvm(6360): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0052
05-30 12:10:14.503: W/dalvikvm(6360): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/sendsapp/ExtendedMail; (1630)
05-30 12:10:14.503: W/dalvikvm(6360): Link of class 'Lcom/example/sendsapp/ExtendedMail;' failed
05-30 12:10:14.503: D/dalvikvm(6360): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2a70 at 0x58 in Lcom/example/sendsapp/MailSenderClass$Sender_mail_async;.doInBackground
05-30 12:10:14.523: W/dalvikvm(6360): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x5ccbbb20)
05-30 12:10:14.523: D/AndroidRuntime(6360): procName from cmdline: com.example.sendsapp
05-30 12:10:14.523: E/AndroidRuntime(6360): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.sendsapp
05-30 12:10:14.523: D/AndroidRuntime(6360): file written successfully with content: com.example.sendsapp StringBuffer : ;com.example.sendsapp
```

Ошибка происходит при отправке сообщения.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40807/discussion-on-question-by-green-soldiers-java----javamail).